# Nested collections appropriate naming of the Input elements

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a few nested collections, at the bottom of which are 'Tags' which I'd like the user to be able to add and remove with Javascript before posting back.

In order for the 'Tags' to be sent back to my controller appropriately the INPUT elements must be named appropriately (see this post:  http://jarrettmeyer.com/post/2995732471/nested-collection-models-in-asp-net-mvc-3)

i.e.

```
<input name="Programs[3].Tags[7].Id" value="MyTag" />
```

When my View is first rendered I'm using EditorTemplates and EditorFor to render the HTML which produces the accurate naming for me, most importantly it knows what "numbers" to use.

If i add a tag via Javascript however, I need to add a new INPUT element to the DOM and name it correctly.  How would I get the proper numbers to name my element with Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest ways are probably to parse the numbers out of the ID using a regular expression and add to it, or output hidden fields that contain the two numbers (or the "next") two numbers and read them from there.

Comment: Thanks Danny.  I hate going back through the DOM with Javascript just to log the indices.  Is there no way you know of to drop the index into a hidden element with Razor while it's being generatd?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know of an easy way. I agree that doing it in JS sucks :(

Comment: c'est la vie!  Thanks again Danny.